# How to do pixel perfect movement with Unity3D?

Tags: unity, screen, pixel-art

How would you be able to make sprites move pixel by pixel in Unity3D? I've tried the following things.

- `int x = (int) transform.position.x;`
- `int x = Mathf.FloorToInt(transform.position.x);`
- `int x = Mathf.RoundToInt(transform.position.x);`

I don't know what else to try

Because I'm making an SNES looking game, and when things move, there is very bad pixel crawl in the sprites.

Comment: Depending on what you mean by "pixel crawl", [this question](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/18787/how-does-one-avoid-the-staircase-effect-in-pixel-art-motion) *might* be relevant.

Answer (score 2):

I've done several pixel perfect games in Unity ([the latest one](http://monkeymoon.net/tiny-avengers).

Your first thought is the one I use, I cast every position as an integer. Something like :

```
Vector2 pos = transform.position;
Vector2 clamped_position = new Vector2((int)pos.x,(int)pos.y);
transform.position = clamped_position;
```

However if you're interested in movement it's a little bit complex but not too hard. The trick here is to update a variable with movement value (in pixel per second). Once the variable describes a movement greater than one pixel, you know that you have to move your GameObject.

Here is what you can find in the LateUpdate method of my GameObject:

```
    private void LateUpdate()
    {
        // Clamp the current movement
        Vector2 clamped_movement = new Vector2((int)_movement.x, (int)_movement.y);
        // Check if a movement is needed (more than 1px move)
        if (clamped_movement.magnitude >= 1.0f)
        {
            // Update velocity, removing the actual movement
            _movement= _movement- clamped_movement;
            if (clamped_movement != Vector2.zero)
            {
                // Move to the new position
                transform.position = ClampVector(transform.position) + clamped_movement;
            }
        }
    }
```

And here is how I update the `_movement` variable when player wants to go left :

```
 public void GoLeft() 
{
    // speed is defined in pixel per second.
    _movement.x -= speed * Time.deltaTime;
}
```

With that in mind you just have to take care of the orthographic size of your camera. Using [this simple trick](https://indiehoodgames.wordpress.com/2013/07/27/pixel-perfect-calculator-for-orthographic-camera-unity3d/) you can be sure that your main camera is correctly set up, and everything should work out.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Dood your marvel game looks nice.